# How to use Count one column and separated by each id

Tags: mysql

i want to count the attendance of my employees separated but its merging together

[My target output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fjMm.png)

My codes

```
 SELECT count(employees_id) as numbers FROM attendance WHERE in_time != ' ' AND out_time != ' 'AND employees_id = 1
 SELECT count(employees_id) as numbers FROM attendance WHERE in_time != ' ' AND out_time != ' 'AND employees_id = 260
```

need help to separated them thanks :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by merging together? Did you try `SELECT count(employees_id) as numbers, employee_id FROM attendance WHERE in_time != ' ' AND out_time != ' ' GROUP BY employees_id;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below - using `group by` with employee_id

```
SELECT employees_id,count(*) as numbers 
FROM attendance WHERE in_time != ' ' AND out_time != ' '
group by employees_id
```